# How to use Parseval' s( Plancherel' s) identity?

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

Let $f\in L^{2} (\mathbb R)$ with $\lim_{t\to \pm \infty} f(t)=0.$ 
Put, $F_{n} (x)= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-n}^{n}e^{itx} f(t) dt, \ (n=1,2,...).$ Fix $\alpha \in (0, \infty)$ and we define $H_{n}(x)$ as follows:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-n}^{n} e^{itx} (f(t+\alpha) -f(t-\alpha))dt = (e^{-i\alpha x}- e^{i\alpha x})F_{n}(x) + H_{n}(x).$$

> **My Question**: How to show $H_{n}(x) \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ in $L^{2}(\mathbb R)$ ?
>   (I guess some where we need to use [Parseval' identity( Plancherel)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity); but I am bit confused, how to use it.)

Edit: @[LutzL](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/115115/lutzl), pointed out below, and in MO, for the same,  I have tried little in that direction:

$$H_{n}(x)= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-n}^{n} e^{itx} (f(t+\alpha) -f(t-\alpha))dt -(e^{-i\alpha x}- e^{i\alpha x}) \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-n}^{n}e^{itx} f(t) dt$$
we may write, $H_{n}(x)= \frac{1}{2\pi} e^{-i\alpha x} \int_{-n+\alpha}^{n+\alpha}e^{itx} f(t) dt- \frac{1}{2\pi} e^{i\alpha x} \int_{-n-\alpha}^{n-\alpha} e^{itx} f(t) dt-(e^{-i\alpha x}- e^{i\alpha x}) \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-n}^{n}e^{itx} f(t) dt;$
Or, we may write,

$H_{n}(x)= \frac{1}{2\pi} e^{-i\alpha x} \int_{-n+\alpha}^{n+\alpha}e^{itx} f(t) dt- \frac{1}{2\pi} e^{i\alpha x} \int_{-n-\alpha}^{n-\alpha} e^{itx} f(t) dt- \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-n-\alpha}^{n+\alpha} e^{itx} f(t+\alpha) dt + \int_{-n+\alpha}^{n+\alpha} e^{itx} f(t-\alpha) dt= I_{1}-I_{2}-I_{3}+I_{4};$

But then,(using one of the above form), we need to show:
 $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{\mathbb R} |H_{n}(x)|^{2} dx=0.$  Now If I interchange the limit and integral (this may not be possible, here, I am doing without rigours), and then I can take limit inside the square, and then after taking limit, each integrals, $I_{i}, (i=1,2,3,4)$, will be becomes over $\mathbb R$; then I think, it will cancels each other;

> Is this o.k or am I missing something, still, I don't see, where we need to use asymptotic behaviours of $f$ (and what does it mean ?, here is $f$ is arbitrary member of $L^{2}$) ? I am wondering, is it possible to get solution without, Plancherel or parsevel somewhere ?

Comment: Can you write down what $H_n(x)$ actually is in terms of integrals with all the common segments cancelled?

Comment: $H_{n}(x)= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-n}^{n} e^{itx} (f(t+\alpha) -f(t-\alpha))dt -(e^{-i\alpha x}- e^{i\alpha x}) \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-n}^{n}e^{itx} f(t) dt$; I don't see terms cancels, even for $n=1$; thanks;

Comment: You could use a shift in the integration variable, $\int_{-n}^n h(x)f(x+α)\,dx=\int_{-n+α}^{n+α} h(x-α)f(x)\,dx$.

Comment: @LUTZ; thanks, as you pointed, out here and in MO; I have tried to workout (which I have edited above);  but I am sorry, I still could not follow you, completely; can explain bit more ? Thanks a lot for the attention;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying the MO answer, You can use that

$$\int_{-n}^ne^{itx} f(t+α)\,dt=\int_{-n+α}^{n+α}e^{i(t-α)x}f(t)\,dt
=e^{-iαx}\int_{-n+α}^{n+α}e^{itx}f(t)\,dt$$

so that

$$\int_{-n}^ne^{itx} f(t+α)\,dt-e^{-iαx}\int_{-n}^{n}e^{itx}f(t)\,dt
=e^{-iαx}\left[\int_{n}^{n+α}-\int_{-n}^{-n+α}\right]e^{itx}f(t)\,dt$$

and analogously

$$\int_{-n}^ne^{itx} f(t-α)\,dt-e^{iαx}\int_{-n}^{n}e^{itx}f(t)\,dt
=e^{iαx}\left[\int_{n-α}^{n}-\int_{-n-α}^{-n}\right]e^{itx}f(t)\,dt$$

so that in total

$$|H_n(x)|\le \left[\int_{-n-α}^{-n+α}+\int_{n-α}^{n+α}\right]|f(t)|\,dt\le \sqrt{4α}\sqrt{\left[\int_{-n-α}^{-n+α}+\int_{n-α}^{n+α}\right]|f(t)|^2\,dt}$$

and because of $f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$ we have that

$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\int_{n-α}^{n+α}|f(t)|^2\,dt<\infty\implies \lim_{|n|\to\infty}\int_{n-α}^{n+α}|f(t)|^2\,dt=0.$$

---

But one can get more than pointwise convergence. Shifting the integration variables the other direction one can define

$$h_n(t)=\begin{cases}
f(t-α)&t\in[n,n+α)\\
f(t+α)&t\in[n-α,n)\\
-f(t-α)&t\in[-n,-n+α)\\
-f(t+α)&t\in[-n-α,-n)\\
0&\text{ everywhere else}
\end{cases}$$

so that $H_n(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty h_n(t)e^{ixt}\,dt$ and by Plancherel identity

$$\|H_n\|_2^2=2\pi\|h_n\|_2^2=2\pi\int_{-α}^α(|f(n+t)|^2+|f(-n+t)|^2)\,dt$$

and from dominated convergence or other asymptotic arguments (see comments) $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|H_n\|_2=0$ follows.

Comment: So, $|H_{n}(x)|^{2}$ is dominated by last integral, you have mention; and it seems, one integral goes to $-\infty$ and another goes to $\infty$; and assumption, $|f(t)|\to 0$ as $t\to \pm \infty$; gives the result; Is this o.k or still am I missing something ?

Comment: Using the present reasoning, you get a bound on $H_n(x)$ that is independent on $x$, only depends on $n$. This is not yet a condition that allows to bound $\|H_n\|_2$.

Comment: I think, now, it clear to me that, $H_{n}(x)\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ point wise; and from this I have to conclude that, $H_{n}(x) \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ in $L^{2}(\mathbb R)$ ? Is this the way or some thing else ?

Comment: Think of $H_n$ being composed of 4 bandlimited functions with the frequencies prescribed by $f(t)$ and phase shifts. Then $H_{m+kN}$ represents non-overlapping frequency bands if $N>2α$ and thus $\sum_k \|H_{m+kN}\|_2^2\le \|f\|_2^2$ by the Plancherel identity. From that $\|H_n\|_2\to0$ follows.

Comment: How the estimate $\sum_{k} ||H_{m+kN}||_{2}^{2} \leq ||f||_{2}^{2}$, will be helpful ? (because here we don't know about, $||f||_{2}$, except it is finite)

Comment: The terms of any convergent series form a sequence that converges to zero.

Comment: Prof. L; thanks for every thing; ah.. your solution is beautiful; -\ D.