# How to use Parseval' identity( Plancherel)?

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, spectral-theory

(May be this is very basic question for MO)

Let $f\in L^{2} (\mathbb R)$ with $\lim_{t\to \pm \infty} f(t)=0.$ Put 
$$F_{n} (x)= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-n}^{n}e^{itx} f(t) dt \ (n=1,2,...)$$ 
Fix $\alpha \in (0, \infty)$ and we define $H_{n}(x)$ as follows:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-n}^{n} e^{itx} (f(t+\alpha) -f(t-\alpha))dt = (e^{-i\alpha x}- e^{i\alpha x})F_{n}(x) + H_{n}(x)$$

> **My Question**: Can we expect to prove: $H_{n}(x) \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ in $L^{2}(\mathbb R)$ ?

I guess some where we need to use [Parseval' identity( Plancherel)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity); but I am bit confused, how to use it.

Thanks

Comment: Please do not ask questions simultaneously on Math.StackExchange and on MathOverflow. Pick just one site and wait a few days for an answer. Posting simultaneously to both sites leads to duplication of effort and is frowned upon by both communities. Finally, your question is certainly more appropriate at Math.StackExchange.

Comment: I am migrating the question to MSE, with an additional request that the question be closed there as a duplicate. Cross-posting is very much frowned upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As proposed in ([How to use Parseval' s( Plancherel' s) identity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685680/how-to-use-parseval-s-plancherel-s-identity)), You can use that

$$\int_{-n}^ne^{itx} f(t+α)\,dt=\int_{-n+α}^{n+α}e^{i(t-α)x}f(t)\,dt
=e^{-iαx}\int_{-n+α}^{n+α}e^{itx}f(t)\,dt$$

etc. to reduce the expression for $H_n$ to integrals over the segments $[\pm n-α,\pm n+α]$. Then apply the asymptotic behavior of $f$ for large arguments.